# CSS - Creating custom stretching bars

Tags: html, css, image, mobile, desktop

I want to make a custom bar. Which consists of the following:

Let's say I cut such resources from photoshop:
[image]

I want to dynamically set height (in % or depending on platfrom (mobile/desktop)) to this bar container and recieve the following behaviour:

- left and right images stick to left and right corner of the container accordingly
- left and right images keeps their aspect ratio
- middle image stretches (or repeats) to feel the whole bar.

Now I got it working but only with manually set hieghts:

```
.container {
  width:80%;
  top:3%;
  height:152px;
  float:left;
  display: table;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
  transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
}

.left, .right, .middle {
  display:table-cell;
  text-indent: -9999px;
}

.left, .right {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}

.left {
  background-image: url("...");
  width: 121px;
}

.right {
  background-image: url("...");
  width: 115px;
}

.middle {
  background-image: url("...");
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

The problem is that I entered the value of the images (width, height) and that doesn't fit my needs. I want images to be bigger then the actual bar, so I can use the same images for desktop/mobile etc. I want to dynamically set bar contrainer's height and get it stretch properly.

I also want to run animation on bar's container width and see it stretching. Is that possible?

Comment: SVG would be optimal i suspect.

Comment: How do I use it? What If I only have 3 pngs which is marked by red rectangles above?